# Is there an implementation of org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils for .Net?

Tags: c#, java, .net, apache-commons

I'm porting over a Java project that I wrote which uses the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class (particularly the

```
escapeXml
unescapeXml
escapeHtml
unescapeHtml
```

methods).  Is there a .Net equivalent?  Or perhaps some totally logical bit of C# code that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using System.Web for HTML there is:

- [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx)
- [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

For XML escaping you can use the [SecurityElement.Escape method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) in the System.Security namespace. However, there's no equivalent to unescape it that I am aware of. You would have to write your own method that replaces the encoded XML, such as `&lt;` and `&amp;` etc. with their equivalents. The link for the escape method lists the other items.

Comment: I'm voting this up as half the answer (just need the XML part) and for responding damn fast!

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say you nailed this one.  XML unescaping is actually the most important thing for the task I'm currently, but knowing that there isn't a place to look in the system namespace is at least better than reading MSDN articles all day.

Comment: Oh yes, Mageed's response is damn fast, beats me by miles.

Comment: @Jason: Luke's response shows an example method so that saves you rolling your own. Also notice that others have suggested HttpServerUtility instead of HttpUtility. The encoding/decoding is similar, however the difference is that HttpServerUtility is in the context of a website and exposes the functionality via the `Server` object and uses HttpUtility internally. OTOH outside of that context you can use HttpUtility directly. So it boils down to what you have available depending on your project type.

Comment: @Ahmad: The `HtmlEncode`/`HtmlDecode` methods on `HttpServerUtility` are static and can be called directly, not just via the `Server` object exposed in ASP.NET. However, since those methods just pass straight through to the equivalent `HttpUtility` methods it makes more sense to just use `HttpUtility` directly.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class StringEscapeUtils
{
    public static string EscapeXml(string unescaped)
    {
        return SecurityElement.Escape(unescaped);
    }

    public static string UnescapeXml(string escaped)
    {
        return escaped.Replace("&lt;", "<")
                      .Replace("&gt;", ">")
                      .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
                      .Replace("&apos;", "'")
                      .Replace("&amp;", "&");
    }

    public static string EscapeHtml(string unescaped)
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unescaped);
    }

    public static string UnescapeHtml(string escaped)
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(escaped);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the effort to wrap these various functions into a StringEscapeUtils class.  These responses are neck and neck in terms of usefulness.  I'm voting them both up, but I had to pick one as the "Answer" so I went with the first.  You sir have certainly earned yor 17.1K reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) and [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) for the Html replacements. Your options for XML escaping can be found [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility%28VS.85%29.aspx) Class

HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode, HtmlDecode, UrlDecode etc etc...

Also for XML:
[System.Xml.XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert_methods.aspx)
[System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28VS.80%29.aspx)